# Canonical form of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I want to solve the following PDE using canonical form:

$$xu_{xx} + 2x^2u_{xy} = u_x - 1$$

I have found the characteristic curves $\xi = y$ and $\eta = y-x^2$. By computing $u_{xx}$ and $u_{xy}$, I got the following (hopefully correct) relation :
$$4x^3u_{\xi\eta} = -1$$
How do I get the general solution from this?

The correct solution is $u(x,y) = x+f(x^2 - y) + g(y)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have now solved it by putting $x^3 = (\xi - \eta)^{3/2}$ and then integrating the canonical equation will give the given solution.

**Edit(Complete solution):** 
Comparing the given PDE with the general form $A(x, y)u_{xx} + B(x, y)u_{xy} + C(x, y)u_{yy} = Φ(x, y,u,u_x,u_y)$ we find 
$$A = x, B= 2x^2, C = 0$$

Now, the characteristic curves can be found by the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{B \pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A} = 0, 2x$

Integrating, we find the 2 curves as $y = $constant and $y-x^2 = $constant, so we choose 
$$\xi = y,\qquad \eta = y-x^2$$ 
and apply the relations found by chain rule for differentiating $u$ w.r.t. $\xi$ and $\eta$:

$u_x = u_ξξ_x + u_ηη_x, u_y = u_ξξ_y + u_ηη_y,$

$u_{xx} = u_{ξξ}ξ^2_x + 2u_{ξη}ξ_xη_x + u_{ηη}η^2_x+ u_ξξ_{xx} + u_ηη_{xx}$

$u_{xy} = u_{ξξ}ξ_xξ_y + u_{ξη} (ξ_xη_y + ξ_yη_x) + u_{ηη}η_xη_y + u_ξξ_{xy} + u_ηη_{xy},$

$u_{yy} = u_{ξξ}ξ^2_y + 2u_{ξη}ξ_yη_y + u_{ηη}η^2_y + u_ξξ_{yy} + u_ηη_{yy}$

and substituting in original equation will give $4x^3u_{\xi\eta} = -1$

We want to eliminate $x$ so that equation consists only of $\xi$ and $\eta$, so put $$x^3 = (\xi - \eta)^{3/2}$$ then integrate equation once w.r.t. variable $\xi$ , then with $\eta$ to get the given solution.

Comment: That's splendid. This answer could be improved if you add the full solution. Then both the question and the answer would be well received by the community and could help someone in the future looking for a similar problem

Comment: @YuriyS I have now added all the steps

Comment: thank you. Once the grace period passes, you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 3):

$$xu_{xx} + 2x^2u_{xy} -u_x =- 1$$

Equation is linear. Then
$$u=u_h+u_p$$

where $u_p$ is is particular solution(we can take $\; u_p=x\;$),

$u_h$ is solution homogeneus equation $xu_{xx} + 2x^2u_{xy} -u_x =0$.

After change $\quad \xi = x^2-y,\quad \eta = y\quad$ we get
$$u_{\xi\eta}=0,$$
$$u_h=f(\xi)+g(\eta)=f(x^2-y)+g(y),$$
$$u=u_h+u_p=f(x^2-y)+g(y)+x$$